# Save complete Simulink SimState periodically or each time a predicate is true during a simulation

Tags: matlab, simulink

I am trying to find a way to generate multiple intermediate SimState objects during a Simulink sim run, at predefined instants, letting the simulation run to its specified StopTime.

The documentation says it is only possible to save the complete final state, but maybe there's a way ?

Comment: In model configuration under "Data Import/Export" there is an option called States. That should get states for all time steps. Does that get what you want?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however  the simulation runs for thousands of integration steps and I just need to take a hundred of snapshots or so per run so full state saving is way too much. For a bit of context, I am running these simuations as part of stochastic tree search optimization process, so that's hundreds of thousands of simulation runs, SimState roughly correspond to backtracking points in the tree search. Simulations are started programmatically.

Comment: See whether the answer https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/45077-run-a-simulink-model-for-a-certain-amount-of-time-and-pause helps. I do not know any better way.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to run the model from the Simulink user interface then you'd need to write a custom block that would pause the model, save the simstate and then restart the simulation, at specific intervals.  But the easier approach would be to run the model from the command line, doing something like the following:

```
% Define stop times and preallocate a cell array to save the simstates
stop_times = 1:10; % one second intervals upto 10 seconds
sim_states = cell(1,numel(stop_times));

% Run the model in a loop, saving the simstate at the required times
for tdx = 1:numel(stop_times)

   if tdx == 1
      % First simulation
      sim_out = sim('mdl_name', 'StopTime', num2str(stop_times(tdx)), 'SaveFinalState', 'on', ...
             'LoadInitialState', 'off', 'SaveCompleteFinalSimState', 'on',...
             'FinalStateName', 'final_simstate');
   else
      % subsequent simulations
      assignin('base', 'new_simstate', sim_states{tdx-1});
      sim_out = sim('mdl_name', 'StartTime', num2str(stop_times(tdx-1)),...
             'StopTime', num2str(stop_times(idx)), 'SaveFinalState', 'on', ...
             'LoadInitialState', 'on','InitialState', 'new_simstate',...
             'SaveCompleteFinalSimState', 'on',...
             'FinalStateName', 'final_simstate');
   end

   % store the simstate
   sim_states{tdx} = sim_out.get('final_simstate');
end
```

The above code assumes variables are loaded form the `Base` workspace but can easily be modified to get it from the model workspace or a function workspace.